# Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, cookies

I want put Json file in cookies and display in html but not work . Here is my code

services

```
.factory('dataServices',dataServices);




    function dataServices(){

        var cart =[];
            var services = {
                            cart    : cart,
                            addCart : addCart
                }
        return services
                          function addCart(tensp,gia,img,sl){
                            cart.push({tensp:tensp,gia:gia,img:img,sl:sl})
                        }
    }
```

And in js

```
function shopController(dataServices,$cookies){
        var vm=this;
    vm.cart = dataServices.cart;
   vm.cookies = $cookies.getObject('cart'); // when I add it have error

        vm.add = function(tensp,gia,img){
            dataServices.addCart(tensp,gia,img,1);
                $cookies.putObject('cart',vm.cart);
                   console.log($cookies.getObject('cart'))
                    }
}
```

Html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="vm.add(data.tensp,data.gia,data.img)">
                Add to Cart</button>
```

Here is data display in console.log

```
[{"tensp":"CPU INTEL CORE I5","gia":"400","img":"item14.jpg","sl":1}]
```

But when I try write : `vm.cookies = $cookies.getObject('cart');`
It have error

> Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 in console

[image]
WHere is my wrong . Please help me

Comment: what result you are getting on console.log($cookies.get('cart')) line?

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS it's getObject i edited , and I getting data in question

Comment: Can you open developer tools->application->cookies->yourdomain.com and screenshot what it contains?

Comment: Can you try parsing your result while assigning it to your vm.cookies. As like vm.cookies = JSON.parse($cookies.getObject('cart'));

Comment: @Leguest I add it . Can you show me where my wrong

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS I try it end i get error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JSON.stringify to turn Javascript Object to string 
Try this :

```
JSON.stringify($cookies.getObject('cart'));
```